# Python Function Class

Tags: python, json, facebook, class, python-2.7

Related:  [Facebook Python " ValueError: too many values to unpack"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20893520/facebook-python-valueerror-too-many-values-to-unpack)

Confused and would really like to understand this...

I know this API URL will return the Json data I want: "https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=moving&type=post&limit=10000&access_token=XXXXXX|XXXXXXX"

Sample Data:

```
{"data":[{"id":"100003992227166_343136419162763",
          "from":{"name":"Taiwo Babalola Oladele","id":"100003992227166"},
          "story":"Taiwo Babalola Oladele shared Gloria Copeland's status update.",
          "story_tags":{"0":[{"id":"100003992227166",
                              "name":"Taiwo Babalola Oladele",
                              "offset":0, "length":22, "type":"user"},],
                       "30":[{"id":"109580399076690",
                              "name":"Gloria Copeland",
                              "offset":30,"length":15,"type":"page"},
```

So I tried the above API URL above into the code below to build a .csv:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import csv
import json
import urllib
import sys
import time
import re

class FacebookSearch:
    def __init__(self,
        query   = 'https://graph.facebook.com/search.{mode}?{query}&{access_token}'
    ):
        access_token = 'XXXXXX|XXXXX'

    def search(self, q, mode='json', **queryargs):
        queryargs['q'] = q
        query = urllib.urlencode(queryargs)
        return query


def write_csv(fname, rows, header=None, append=False, **kwargs):
    filemode = 'ab' if append else 'wb'
    with open(fname, filemode) as outf:
        out_csv = csv.writer(outf, **kwargs)
        if header:
            out_csv.writerow(header)
        out_csv.writerows(rows)

def main():
    ts = FacebookSearch()
    data = ts.search('appliance', type='post')
    js = json.loads(data)



    messages = ([msg['created_time'],  msg['id']] for msg in js.get('data', []))

    write_csv('fb_washerdryer.csv', messages, append=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I get a traceback of:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./facebook_washer_dryer1.sh", line 43, in <module>
    main()
  File "./facebook_washer_dryer1.sh", line 34, in main
    js = json.loads(data)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/json/__init__.py", line 307, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/json/decoder.py", line 319, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/json/decoder.py", line 338, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-46-164 ~]$
```

I understand what the person on the related link was saying but I guess I kinda don't.

I am not sure when I define my search class that I am doing wrong.

Comment: Your code is so far from making sense that it's really hard to try to explain how to fix it. I'm guessing you copied and pasted bits from some blog or other source; if you can tell use where the original `FacebookSearch` class came from, it would be easier to explain what you're doing wrong.

Comment: Also, you've tagged this "python-2.7", but your error traceback clearly shows that you're using 2.6, not 2.7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't written any code that even *builds* that URL, much less code that downloads the document at that URL.

As a side note, the code you posted here (and in your original question) has some `SyntaxError`s that make it unusable as-is. Also, you're using Python 2.6, but defining classes without a base class, which means you will get classic classes—you don't want that. I'll fix both of those as I go along.

---

First, in your `__init__` method, you create a couple of local variables, `query` and `access_token`, and then do nothing with them. This isn't going to do you any good. If you want to create variables that other methods can use, you have to create *attributes of your object*, not local variables. Like this:

```
class FacebookSearch(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.url_format = 'https://graph.facebook.com/search.{mode}?{query}&{access_token}'
        self.access_token = 'XXXXXX|XXXXX'
```

Now, you can use these variables. But you have to actually use them. To get variables pasted into a format string, you have to call the `.format` method on that format string. Like this:

```
    def make_search_url(self, q, mode='json', **queryargs):
        queryargs['q'] = q
        query = urllib.urlencode(queryargs)
        url = self.url_format.format(mode=mode, query=query, 
                                     access_token=self.access_token, **queryargs)
        return url
```

So, now we have a full URL, like https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=moving&type=post&limit=10000&access_token=XXXXXX|XXXXXXX. So far, so good. But that's still just a URL—a string. You want to get the document *at* that URL. For that, you need to call some function that downloads a URL. Like [`urllib2.urlopen`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html):

```
    def search(self, q, mode='json', **queryargs):
        url = self.make_search_url(q, mode, **queryargs)
        page = urllib2.urlopen(url)
        return page.read()
```

And *now* we have a method that you call that builds a URL from your query, looks up the resource at that URL, and returns the data from that resource. So now we're getting close. You can call it like this:

```
data = ts.search('appliance', type='post')
```

However, there's still one problem. That `type='post'` isn't going to do anything. You pass it to `search`. Then `search` passes it to `make_search_url`. Which passes it to `format`. Then, since you have no placeholder named `type` in the format string, it does nothing.

I'm not sure what you wanted to do with that `type='post'` here. If you wanted to make it use a POST instead of a GET for the request… then you shouldn't be putting query strings in your URL in the first place. If you wanted it to do something different, I can't guess what that something different might have been.

The easy solution here is that, if you don't know why you're doing it, don't do it:

```
data = ts.search('appliance')
```

Now this will return a 404 because pasting that `XXXXXX|XXXXX` on the end is obviously not going to work. It has to be something of the form `access_token=XXXXXXXX`, and that `XXXXXXXX` has to be a token that you got from an OAuth authentication, which you haven't done anywhere.

Comment: Incredible answer for a question filled with nonsense code. Never seen anything like this on SO. Kudos to you sir.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for the explanation.  I did the OAuth in a different and just replaced it with "xxx" for this question.